# In GitLab ci, how to run shared runner if my specific runner is not available?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I configured a specific runner for gitlab-ci on a local server. It worked like a charm, and it is 3 times faster that the shared runner on gitlab.com. So far, so great.

**But I was wondering what will happen if my local server was not available**. In this scenario, all the jobs of the pipeline will be in pending (waiting to the specific runner). If so, all projects deployments could be stuck for a while.

I tried some configurations in .gitlab-ci.yml to run the shared runner if my specific runner was not available. But all my tests failed.

## What I did

My idea was to set 2 tags for the runners. The first one for my specific runner and the second one for the shared runner.

```yaml
.tags: &tags
  - my-custom-runner
  - shared
```

But in this configuration, if my-custom-runner was not available, I had this error in the gitlab-ci job :

[this job is stuck because you don't have any active runners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66H1z.png)

Has anyone figured out how to do this yet ? I didn't find related documentation on this topic.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks a lot.

## Additional information

This configuration works if my-custom-runner is available :

```yaml
.tags: &tags
  - my-custom-runner
```

This configuration works too and runs in the gitlab shared runner.

```yaml
.tags: &tags
  - shared
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this one? I have the same question.